# disable user interaction in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I need to disable total user interaction during a play of a litle video, i already tried to set the style of the control to none : `MPMovieControlStyleNone`, and put a `UIView` above the `MPMoviePlayerController`, but when i pinch the video disappears, and the sound still playing, like i dismissed the video, but it still playing on the background, plus the user interaction is disabled.
Heres how i do:

```
-(IBAction)startGame:(id)sender
{
    NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Teste" ofType:@"m4v"]];
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayer];

    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

    mBlankView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:moviePlayer.view.frame];
    mBlankView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [mBlankView setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];
    [mBlankView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:mBlankView];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To disable Movieplayer control completely u need to disable your movieplayers view userinteraction as follows:

```
moviePlayer.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: Doesnt work `[moviePlayer.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];`
    `moviePlayer.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`